# Typescript error compiling Aurelia with Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, aurelia

Using IntelliJ Idea 2016.2 I'm encountering this error typing to compile an aurelia project generated with

```
aurelia_project/generators/binding-behavior.ts(2,52): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'aurelia-cli'.
```

aurelia cli is plainly in `node_modules` for both local and global. Given the path should this file even compile? perhaps it should be ignored?

if I understand tsconfig and my idea settings, these shouldn't even be built

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./typings/index.d.ts",
    "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

[image: idea settings]

`au run --watch` starts fine

How can I fix this issue so that Idea can build the project without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add generators folder to exclude list - that folder is used internally by Aurelia CLI(if i remember correctly).

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "aurelia_project"
],
```

Comment: I could look it ups, but since this is an SO question, and I'm new to typescript perhaps you could provide the json that is required for that?

Comment: updated the answer to include the relevant exclude section

Answer (score 2):

Your will get the same issue when running the compiler in terminal - neither Idea (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17991) not tsc itself support `filesGlob`, this is atom-specific option. So all files are compiled. And, as no .d.ts for  'aurelia-cli' can be found in the project, compiler errors are reported.

to work out the issue, you can either change the `tsconfig.json` to make sure that only need files are compiled, or disable TypeScript compiler and use aurelia to build your project